# how to use fingerprint id to sign in to apple ID

Tags: apple-id, keychain, touch-id

When updating my Mac, I often get a password popup like the following.
[image]

Why does the keychain not remember my password from the last 100 times I entered it.  And why does it not offer me the fingerprint option?    I have my Touch ID options set as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you reset the Touch ID completely and add it back again. It can help you to fix the issue.

1. Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> while it's rebooting to enter Recovery Mode
2. Launch Terminal.
3. Enter the following:

   ```
   xartutil --erase-all
   ```
4. Press Return.
5. Type Yes when prompted to confirm.
6. Press Enter.
7. Quit Terminal.
8. Restart your Mac in normal mode.
9. Setup your Touch ID again and it should work.

Comment: Is that a serious comment?  Sorry, but how can I start a terminal in recovery mode?  It gives me several options, but not that one.

Comment: Here is a similar issue for iPhone. http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/08/touch-id-not-working-in-the-app-store-heres-an-easy-fix-for-it.html

Comment: @JimNewton: Why do you doubt the shared solution? https://osxdaily.com/2017/12/21/delete-touch-bar-data-mac/ Check here too.

Comment: The comment at http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/08/touch-id-not-working-in-the-app-store-heres-an-easy-fix-for-it.html does not seem to work.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure the shared solution was legit, as when I tried to research it  before blindly typing something I don't understand, All its uses that I found are associated with cleaning the system, and wiping all the disks before selling the computer to someone else.

I also wonder what Udhy's confidence level is.  As other people seem to be reporting the same thing and the general consensus seems to be that this is just an annoying Apple Bug.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for iOS or macOS? Your link is for iPhone!

Comment: Yes the link is indeed for iPhone but the problem seems related. Seems anyway. Yes I'm using a MacBook not iPhone.

Comment: Udhy, I tried your suggestion, and now when I reboot the system the login prompt no longer recognizes my password.

Comment: After I tried several times to type the password, it recommended that I reboot for password recovery. I rebooted, it asked me my wifi password, then my Apple ID and password, then it told me it can't read the disk, that I should reboot again. I tried to restart, now it fails to boot at all.... Are you sure --erase-all is safe? Seems it erased too much.

Comment: The exact message is: An error occurred in mounting your volume.  Restart your computer to try again.

Comment: WARNING WARNING I would advise against anyone using this solution. After applying the recipe my system no longer recognized my password, and would not let me reset the password, and could not even locate my disk.  I had to go to the Apple store service bar to have the system erased and os reinstalled.